# como fazer para criar etiquetas com o relatórios rápidos

Tags: delphi, fast-reports

Eu fiz uma impressão por etiqueta funciona bem, para imprimir uma etiqueta para cada produto existente ou o MasterData faz corretamente.

Só que para Etiqueta ou que eu queria que fosse o mesmo produto, se repetisse um acordo com a quantidade mínima usada pelo usuário, uma questão é como eu faço isso com o MasterData? É possível? Eu sei que para imprimir somente um produto certo é fazer uma busca e deixar o armazenamento no DataSet mais do mesmo modo que ele irá imprimir 1 vez e não uma quantidade certa. EX: usuário digitou o número 3 ai aparece assim em outro nível

PRODUTO 1 PRODUTO 1 PRODUTO 1

eu fiz assim:

```
procedure TFm_Gerar.SELECIONARClick(Sender: TObject);
    var
    qtd : String;
    cont,ndias : integer;
    resultado,data : TDateTime;
    begin
    InputQuery('qtd','Informe quantas datas:',qtd);
    cont:= 1;
    ndias := dm.CDS_VERIFICA_PRODUTO.FieldByname('validade').AsInteger;
    data := Date;
    RESULTADO := data + ndias;
    if messagedlg('Deseja imprimir a 
    data?',MtConfirmation,mbYes,mbNo],0)=mrYes then
    begin

            while qtd >= (IntToStr(cont)) do
              begin
               cont:= cont +1;
              //  dm.data.LoadFromFile('data.fr3');
              //  dm.data.Variables['qtda'] := IntToStr(qtd); 
                dm.data.ShowReport;

              end;
          end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá! Existem muitas formas de fazer isso.
O modo mais prático é você criar uma tabela temporaria vinculada a um DataSet. Nessas informações virtuais você realiza o processo de impressão que você desejar.

Algo assim:

```
// Cria tabela temporaria
tabelaTemp.FileName:= 'nometabelatemporaria.xml';
with TabelaTemp do
begin
   FieldDefs.Clear;
   fieldDefs.Add( 'NOME', ftString, 60 );
   IndexDefs.Clear;
end;
TabelaTemp.CreateDataSet;
TabelaTemp.Active:= True;

qrConsulta.First;  // <---- Dataset ou componentes de dados que possui a informação a imprimir

while not qrConsulta.eof do
begin
   for i:= 0 to nQuantidade-1 do
   begin
       TabelaTemp.Insert;
       TabelaTemp.FieldByName( 'NOME' ).asString:= qrConsulta.FieldByName( 'NOME' ).asString;
       TabelaTemp.Post;
   end;
   next;
end;

TabelaTemp.first;
// A seguir roda o .fr3 vinculado ao dataset de sua TabelaTemp

frxReport1.ShowReport;
```

Assim você estará executando o relatorio uma vez sobre uma serie de dados.
A tabela temporaria nem precisa ser salva, somente permitirá que a replicação seja realizada. Em um exemplo funcional eu exibo uma lista de itens e permito que os usuários escolham as quantidades desejadas em cada um deles, apertem o botão imprimir e o sistema lista as respectivas etiquetas.
Com poucas mudanças no código você também consegue fazer desta forma. Sucesso!

Comment: e o procedimento que eu fiz citados continua?

Comment: Não compreendi o que vc se refere? consegue melhorar a pergunta?

Comment: eu faço o codigo que me passou junto com o que eu fiz?

Comment: Você deve buscar entender com base nas informações que te passei. Se você observar seu método chama varias vezes a rotina de impressão, o que para relatórios de páginas inteiras (como cartas) até serviria, mas, para etiquetas não.
A abordagem que usei é diferente, baseia-se na mesma impressão com uma gama de dados com as informações para que o fique fácil manter o relatório independentemente dos dados.  Logo, você deve escolher um caminho ou outro.